# Declaring a Static Structure and returning its address, not a pointer or reference?

Tags: c++

im tasked with taking a users inputted start and stop times, and compute and display the difference. We need a header file MyTime that contains the structure with hours, minutes, and seconds. My main function prompts the user to input the time and it goes directly into the MyTime Structure. Then, DetermineElapsedTime function is called and passed two pointers to the two structures containing the user entered times, **Then store the pointer it returns in a type "Pointer to MyTime" Variable**. That is where im having the trouble. A hint is given as well for this: "Declare a static MyTime structure in DetermineElapsedTime, store the elapsed time in it, then return its address. Returning a pointer or reference to an automatic object is always wrong".

Any Help is greatly appreciated; what i have so far is below. Right now my TimeDiff variable that calls the DetermineElapsedTime function is returning garbage. And im not sure if i set up the structures properly. I am new to C++ so any guidance is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

MAIN FUNCTION:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C1A7E1_MyTime.h"
using namespace std;

MyTime* DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime* StartTime, const MyTime* StopTime);

int main()
{
    MyTime StartTime, StopTime;
    MyTime *TimeDiff;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++);
    {
        cout << "Please enter a Start and Stop Time that is space seperated on "
            "the same line in the following colon-delimited format "
            "(HH:MM:SS): ";

        // Declare Colon delimiters
        char Colon1, Colon2, Colon3, Colon4;

        // Get users input
        cin >> StartTime.hours >> Colon1 >> StartTime.minutes >> Colon2
            >> StartTime.seconds >> StopTime.hours >> Colon3
            >> StopTime.minutes >> Colon4 >> StopTime.seconds;

        TimeDiff = DetermineElapsedTime(&StartTime, &StopTime);

        cout << "\nThe time elapsed from " << StartTime.hours << Colon1
            << StartTime.minutes << Colon2 << StartTime.seconds << " to "
            << StopTime.hours << Colon3 << StopTime.minutes
            << Colon4 << StopTime.seconds << " is " << TimeDiff;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

DetermineElapsedTime Function:

```
#include "C1A7E1_MyTime.h"
#define HR_SECONDS 3600;
#define MIN_SECONDS 60;
using namespace std;

MyTime *DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime *StartTime, const MyTime *StopTime)
{
    // Declare static MyTime structure to store elapsed time in
    MyTime static ElapsedTime;

    // Pull out Start Time in seconds
    long int Start_Hr = StartTime->hours * HR_SECONDS;
    int Start_Min = StartTime->minutes * MIN_SECONDS;
    int Start_Sec = StartTime->seconds;

    // Total the number of seconds in start time
    int TotalStart = Start_Hr + Start_Min + Start_Sec;

    // Pull out Stop Time in seconds
    long int Stop_Hr = StopTime->hours * HR_SECONDS;
    int Stop_Min = StopTime->minutes * MIN_SECONDS;
    int Stop_Sec = StopTime->seconds;

    // Total the number of seconds in stop time
    int TotalStop = Stop_Hr + Stop_Min + Stop_Sec;
    
    // Find the difference in start/stop time
    long int TimeDiff = (TotalStop - TotalStart);
    
    // If stop time is less than start time (new day) then make it positive
    if (TimeDiff <= 0)
    {
        TimeDiff = -TimeDiff;
    }
    
    // Find time difference in hours
    int ElapsedHr = TimeDiff / HR_SECONDS;
    ElapsedTime.hours = ElapsedHr;

    // Find time difference in minutes
    int FirstSub = ElapsedHr * HR_SECONDS;
    int remainingSeconds = (TimeDiff) - FirstSub;
    int ElapsedMin = remainingSeconds / MIN_SECONDS;
    ElapsedTime.minutes = ElapsedMin;

    // Find time difference in seconds
    int SecondSub = ElapsedMin * MIN_SECONDS;
    remainingSeconds = remainingSeconds - SecondSub;
    int ElapsedSec = remainingSeconds;
    ElapsedTime.seconds = ElapsedSec;

    //Return address of elapsed time
    return(&ElapsedTime);
}
```

MyTime Structure / Header File

```
#ifndef C1A7E1_MYTIME_H // Header Guard
#define C1A7E1_MYTIME_H

//Structure Definition and declaration of structur variables
struct MyTime
{
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
};

#endif
```

Comment: I'm confused, what's the problem? I mean besides the fact that I would fire you on the spot if you returned a pointer to a static field like that in my code base. You seem to have returned the pointer as requested.

Comment: You are allowed to return a pointer or reference. The sentence is written that way because "automatic" is mutually exclusive with "static". Returning a pointer or reference to a static variable is fine.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `cout << TimeDiff` to do? `TimeDiff` in `main` is a pointer to a `MyTime` struct. (It's something completely different in `DetermineElapsedTime`, which I don't love.)

Comment: So i was originally having issues with displaying the time in a 2-digit time format with TimeDiff, but as @Nathan Pierson pointed out i already had a pointer to a MyTime struct, so i did cout<<TimeDiff->hours, etc and that did the trick. But Nathan what dont you love about the DetermineElapsedTime function, could it be condensed, or improved any insight would be greatly appreciated, again im new to all this.

Comment: What I meant in that remark is specifically that I don't love how you use `TimeDiff` to mean two fairly different things in different parts of your code. My assumption is that you expected `cout << TimeDiff` to print out the number of seconds that had elapsed, because that's what _one_ version of `TimeDiff` is. The actual behavior of `DetermineElapsedTime` seems pretty reasonable to me. A lot of the stuff I'd do differently is trying to increase variable name clarity especially when different variables have different units.

Comment: My biggest problem with this function is one you can't solve, which is that returning a pointer to a static `MyTime` struct instead of returning a struct by value is... I don't understand why you have to do it that way. To learn a lesson about `static` duration variables? For any actual use case the fact that something like `auto dur1 = DetermineElapsedTime(start1, end1); auto dur2 = DetermineElapsedTime(start2, end2);` will invalidate the contents of `dur1` seems like a major design flaw.

Comment: Who gave you this task? It's horrible! There's absolutely no reason to use pointers here, using `MyTime` as a time point and a duration is confusing, using a static variable here makes absolutely no sense and returning a pointer to it makes even less sense.